# Using Nest to dynamically tokenizing a field into completion fields in eastern languages

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I would like some help on tokenizing a field into multiple inputs in c#, where the input is in a south-eastern language (Thai).

This way i can put in a list of strings of these words into the suggestion input and create a proper completion. I am not sure if i can use Nest or i have to combine my solution with icu.net or Lucene.Net.ICU

Thankz in advance

Comment: I would suggest looking into a NLP [natural language processing] package. I use Stanford NLP, it can tokenize and do much more.

Answer (score 0):

[The Elasticsearch ICU Analysis plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu.html) integrates the Lucene ICU module into Elasticsearch. You can configure a field mapping to use a custom analyzer configured with [`icu_tokenizer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu-tokenizer.html) and other use case specific configurations that you require.

If you require capabilities beyond the supported integrations, then you may need to look at NLP packages and approaches as Wurd suggested in the comments.

Comment: woud this allow me to convert one field, lets say name into a list of suggestions on the fly?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. What do you mean by suggestions? Like autocompletion suggestions? If so, it really depends on the expectations for autocompletion e.g. prefix completion, completion from any term in text, etc. But yes, a `text` or `completion` field can be used for suggestions, with varying levels of suggestion complexity

Comment: yes i do mean autocomplete, and i know how to set it up. But i am stuck at trying to convert a feild (e.g Name) into a list of array using icu_tokenizer

Comment: Why do you need to convert a field into a list of array?

Comment: for the autocomplete to work accurately with the asian language. I have tested around a lot and the auto-suggest wont work well if it does not tokenize words properly. And the thai language does not have spacebar for tokenization

Comment: Have you tried building a custom analyzer that uses analysis components from ICU Analysis plugin, and hooking this up as the analyzer for autocompletion?

Comment: I did but the issue is if the person starts typing with the second word instead of prefix beginning, it wont find. That is one of the requirements. But if i chop the word and make it as a list of suggestions then its fine :)

Comment: Sounds like completion suggester may not be the best approach in this case, and that search on a `text` field may be better. If the analysis outside of indexing approach works for you though, go with it :)

Comment: thankz, was thinking so. Dont know which would turn out to be faster? If we have an ongoing indexing job ... would autocomplete be faster? Thankz again! :D